# How do I work around the fact that Apache needs to be restarted to rotate the logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, logrotate

It seems so "primitive" that HTTPD has to be restarted just to rotate the logs. There has got be other ways to accomplish this!

Note that I do not use nor wish to use AWStats, [one of the ways to solve this problem](http://www.ducea.com/2008/06/04/rotate-apache-logs-using-awstats/).

Using CentOS 5.x on a dedicated server.

Comment: You don't need to restart apache to rotate the logs. [According to this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#pidfile), you need only send a SIGHUP to the PID listed in the PidFile, and apache will close and reopen its logfiles.

Comment: What are you using to rotate your logs?? logrotate should take care of this for you...

Comment: Would a reload be better than a SIGHUP ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to restart, reload is enough:

```
/sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
```

Comment: I have "/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd graceful ; sleep 5"
Can I just replace it with the line above?

Comment: `reload` send a HUP signal to the process. `graceful`, as its mean, doesn't terminate the currently open connections. A side effect is the old log files will not be closed immediately.